# Relational operators evaluation result

Tags: c, language-lawyer, logical-operators

Assume we have an expression like

```
(x > 5)
```

in C language. Is there any guarantee given by the language / standard that the expression will be evaluated to `0` when it's false and to `1` when it's true?

Comment: It could be optimized: in `if (x>5) printf ("hello x=%d\n", x);` the compiler probably won't emit code comparing the result of `x>5` to 1. It would just emit code for the test `x>5` and a conditional jump.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed by the standard.

As per the `C11` standard document, chapter  6.5.8, paragraph 6, [Relational operators]

> Each of the operators `<` (less than), `>` (greater than), `<=` (less than or equal to), and `>=`
>   (greater than or equal to) shall yield `1` if the specified relation is `true` and `0` if it is
>   `false`. The result has type `int`.

Update: Same chapter and paragraph for `C99` standard also.

Comment: @Gopi I am quoting the standard, I guess i'm not allowed to put my own words in that.

Answer (score 0):

In gcc, it will be evaluated as one and zero.
Consider following program

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    if((a > b) == 0)
        printf("a > b is false\n");
    if((a < b) == 1)
        printf("a < b is true\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It gives output

```
a > b is false
a < b is true
```

Comment: The question is whether the standard guarantees something, not what a specific implementation does.